# Rails update multiple records find based on other id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Using Rails 3.2. As shown in the [doc on `update` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update), the `update` finds based on `id`:

```
update(id, attributes)
# id - This should be the id or an array of ids to be updated.

# Updates multiple records
people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

What if I want to update an array found based on other columns? For example:

```
people = { 'cook' => { "first_name" => "David" }, 'server' => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
```

Find people with `role = cook`, then update `first_name = David`; find people with `role = server`, then update `first_name = jeremy`.

I want it to be done in 1 query if possible, and not by SQL. Thanks.

Comment: Try update_all http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

Comment: Did any of the answers worked out for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can Achieve this with [#update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class)

```
people = { 'cook' => { "first_name" => "David" }, 'server' => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }

Person.update_all(people.keys, people.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case I would write my own sql statement. I depends on which database backend you are using.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method doesn't execute 1 SQL query when passed an array of ids and values. If you view the source code for `update`, you will see it loops through the array and executes 2 queries for each record (a find and an update query) to then return an array of updated objects.

If you're happy accepting that you will need to make 2 queries per row, then you can use the following code for finding people by role.

```
people = { 'cook' => { "first_name" => "David" }, 'server' => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }

updated_people = people.keys.map.with_index do |role, index| 
  object = Person.where(role: role).first!
  object.update(people.values[index])
  object
end
```

Note: This code only updates the first record it finds per role because I've assumed there will only be one cook with the first name 'David'.

If you want to only use 1 SQL statement, you should look at doing it in SQL like devanand suggested.